# Why does the sqlite3pp sample behave this way?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

So I try simple [sqlite3pp](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite3pp/) modified a bit [code](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite3pp/source/browse/trunk/testinsert.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3pp.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try {
        sqlite3pp::database db("test.db");

        {
            db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ( email varchar(65) primary key, pass varchar(65))");
            db.execute("INSERT INTO users (email, pass) VALUES ('AAAA', '1234')");
        }

        {
            sqlite3pp::transaction xct(db);

            sqlite3pp::command cmd(db, "INSERT INTO users (email, pass) VALUES (?, ?)");

            cout << cmd.bind(1, "BBBB") << endl;
            cout << cmd.bind(2, "1234") << endl;
            cout << cmd.execute() << endl;

            cout << cmd.reset() << endl;

            cmd.binder() << "CCCC" << "1234";

            cout << cmd.execute() << endl;

            xct.commit();
        }

        {
            sqlite3pp::transaction xct(db, true);

            sqlite3pp::command cmd(db, "INSERT INTO users (email, pass) VALUES (:name, :name)");

            cout << cmd.bind(":name", "DDDD") << endl;

            cout << cmd.execute() << endl;
        }
    }
    catch (exception& ex) {
        cout << ex.what() << endl;
    }
    cin.get();

}
```

First time it gives such output:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

And on second time and forward when I execute it:

```
0
0
1
19
1
column email is not unique
```

Why it does not throw any error sooner than 5th ([SQL error codes](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having had a quick look in the implementation of sqlite3pp, it seems stuff tends to just return error codes, and expects you to check them; it looked like it could be the destructor for the transaction that is throwing an exception, which is why you see your error message at the point that you do.